# How to diagnose network problems?

Tags: windows-7, networking

We have a user getting timeouts from the network and I have no idea how to fix the issue.  Sometimes she gets 3 or 4 a day.  When she tries the same thing again it works.  She is getting the errors from the ERP program (.Net; Windows 7; SQL server 2005; Visual Studio 2008).  We have 2 GB lines going to the server from the switch and no more than 35 users using it at a time.  The hardware guy gave her a new PC, checked the wire, tired a different wire to a different jack (then put the original one back when she still received errors) and switched the port on the switch.  Both him and my boss told me there's nothing they can do.  I find that hard to believe, but being a software developer, my skills are not exceptionally helpful here.

I read about the seven layers but the more I read the less I know what to do.  The problem is intermittent and I can ping her machine and the server (the extent of my networking troubleshooting skills).  This seems like an issue beyond an amateur networker.  Someone else just sent me a timeout so the issue may be more than one location.  Other people could be getting the error and not reporting it.  People here are notorious for not reporting errors and the way this one is being handled I can see why.

I don't like to leave users with problems and this is a good opportunity for me to increase my network skills, a true win-win.  But I need some guidance.  I'll read any good links people post and / or perform any steps they ask.  Please dont type network issue and blindly paste links, been there done that.  That is not useful.

Thanks

Comment: Is your ERP server running on Windows 7?

Comment: Less likely - Can you hard set her network speed instead of auto? It could be an negotiation issue. More likely - Do you have an extra USB ethernet dongle around? If so, maybe install it on her computer and see if that makes the situation change. It sounds like maybe her NIC is failing.

Comment: No, Windows Server 2003 if you mean SQL Server.  There isn't an actual ERP server, just clients that connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Looks like I will leave my job before I find anyone that has a clue.  Thanks anyway, I'll just have to wish them good luck!!